# Iterating a dataProvider in flex

Tags: apache-flex, iterator, dataprovider

I'm wondering... I want to iterate through a dataProvider, in a Component which is based on a DropDownList.
First thing, that it didn't work (it compiled, but never iterated), was:

```
var o:Object;
for each (var o:Object in dataProvider)
{
}
```

I guess it didn't work because a IList doesn't provide Objects, or something someone would be able to explain easily.

I tried something that looks horrible from a efficiency perspective, nonetheless it works. This is it:

```
for (var i:int = 0; i < dataProvider.length; i++)
{
   o = dataProvider.getItemAt(i);
}
```

But it is so horrible that I felt tempted to ask here about another possible solution.

UPDATE:

I'll try to elaborate... I'm making (well, it is made already) a component that, being like a DropDownList, is bindable, not to an index (like selectedIndex="@{variable}"), but to a value of a variable inside of the ArrayCollection.

Say, you have a dataProvider with two objects: `{a:'5', nmb:'five', blabla:'cinco'}` and `{a:'39', nmb:'thirty-nine', blabla:'treinta y nueve'}`.

This component, if declared like this:

```
<com:ddListN idxName="a" selectedN="@{val}" labelField="nmb">
```

Does use `val` to set/get the DropDownList to the proper index, comparing the value with the variable defined in idxName.

Well, this is the entire code (is not that much):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:DropDownList xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                change="ch()">
    <fx:Declarations>
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            private var _selectedN:String;

            public var idxName:String = 'n';

            [Bindable(event="changeSelected")]
            public function get selectedN():String
            {
                return this.selectedItem[idxName];
            }

            public function set selectedN(v:String):void
            {
                var o:Object;
//              for each (var o:Object in dataProvider) @@
                for (var i:int = 0; i < this.dataProvider.length; i++)
                {
                    o = dataProvider.getItemAt(i);
                    if (o[idxName] == v)
                    {
                        this.selectedIndex = i;
                        _selectedN = v;
                        dispatchEvent(new Event("changeSelected"));
                        return; 
                    }

                }
                this.selectedItem = null; // no seleccionar nada (@@?)
                _selectedN = null;
                dispatchEvent(new Event("changeSelected"));
            }

            private function ch():void
            {
                _selectedN = this.selectedItem[idxName];
                dispatchEvent(new Event("changeSelected"));
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:DropDownList>
```

Comment: I'm surprised the first approach doesn't work.  I'm also surprised you're having performance issues with the second approach.  I would have expected the second to be more efficient, because it is a "known" number of loop iterations when the loop starts.  Perhaps you can elaborate on what you're trying to do and/or provide a runnable sample explaining your problems.

Comment: Well, maybe the second approach would still be better than the first if the first one worked... I'll try elaborating more...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually `for each` loops are a little bit slower than normal `for` loops. Take a look at the answer to [For VS Foreach on Array performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010859/for-vs-foreach-on-array-performance-in-as3-flex).

To answer your question, why your `for each` loop doesn`t work. Unfortunatly this type of loop works only for certain types of classes. As far as I know those are:

- `Array`
- `Vector`
- `XML`
- `XMLList`
- and classes that extend `Proxy` that implement the functions needed for `for each` loops. `ListCollectionView` and its subclasses `ArrayCollection` and `XMLListCollection` are the only ones I know of.

Collection classes like `ArrayList` do not work with `for each` loops since they are not native objects in Flash Player (like `Array`) and they don't extend the `Proxy` class.

So, the best thing you can do is to use simple `for` loops and those loops are even faster than the `for each` loops.