# AS3 Array "for each ... in" performance vs. for loop, and guaranteed in order?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

This question is really twofold:

1. How does `for each` looping over an Array compare performance-wise with a simple `for` loop through its elements?
2. Does a loop guarantee in order traversal?  The following code says yes:

> ```
> var sample_array:Array = [];
> for (var i:uint = 0; i < 10000; i++) sample_array.push(i);
> i = 0;
> for each(var value:uint in sample_array) {
>   sample_array[i++] = value;
> }
>
> trace('in order was:', check_in_order(sample_array));
>
> function check_in_order(array:Array):Boolean
> {
>   for (var i:uint = 0, l:uint = array.length; i < l; ++i) {
>     if (array[i] != i) return false;
>   }
>
>   return true;
> }
> ```

but I have heard other (senior-level) engineers swear up and down that the traversal does not always proceed in ascending order!  Is this true?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1010859/for-vs-foreach-on-array-performance-in-as3-flex and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618966/for-each-loop-as3-is-the-direction-guaranteed might be worth a read.

Comment: Take a look at http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1978 too. It's a great article by Jackson Dunstan comparing for, for-in and for-each.

Comment: @Dovyski - post that as an answer and I'll accept it; dude does a great job of benchmarking (only thing that is perhaps lacking is inclusion of an Array of variable size).

Comment: @Joetjah - thanks for that.  Re. the "for each guaranteed in order?" - Jon Skeet got militant with it!  Right to the AS3 to the ECMA documentation, which neither confirms nor denies in order traversal. In Mr. Skeet's words - "It's a bit unsatisfactory, to be honest :("  I've never seen for each Array traversal be out or order in the tests I've run, for what it's worth.

Comment: @Sensei James I've posted my answer :) About what you said, I agree: the only thing that is lacking is an Array of variable size. However I don't believe it could hurt the performance during *read* operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As demonstrated by [Jackson Dunstan](http://jacksondunstan.com/articles/1978), who compared `for`, `for each` and `for in` with different collections (arrays, vectors, etc), the performance ranking is (from fastest to slowest):

1. `for`
2. `for each`
3. `for in` (extremely slow)

In all cases `for` is the fastest of all. In particular when used with arrays or vectors, `for` has an overwhelming performance. Those are the numbers for all collections (smaller means faster):

[image: Loop Speed Redux by Jackson Dunstan]

Answer (score 1):

here is fixed post from Adrian

```
var size:Number = 10000000;
var arr:Array = [];
var time:Number, o:Object, i:int;
// fill container
for (i = 0; i < size; i++) arr[i] = i;

// for i
time = getTimer();
for (i=0; i<arr.length; i++){ arr[i]; }
trace("for test: "+(getTimer()-time)+"ms");

// for i reversed
time = getTimer();
for (i=arr.length; i>0; i--) { arr[i]; }
trace("for reversed test: "+(getTimer()-time)+"ms");

// for each
time = getTimer();
for each(o in arr) { o; }
trace("for each test: "+(getTimer()-time)+"ms");

// Result
for test: 212ms
for reversed test: 26ms
for each test: 103ms
```

Comment: `For in` here is actually `For each in`. Added `For in` and got this result:
for test: 818ms        
[trace] for reversed test: 418ms        
[trace] for in test: 224ms        
[trace] for each in test: 168ms

Comment: thx already fixed comments ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Please check my post [Flex Array Performance: For vs. ForEach](http://www.redcodelabs.com/2009/07/flex-array-performance-for-vs-foreach/)

Some code

```
var size:Number = 10000000;
var arr:Array = [];
for (var i:int=0; i
var time:Number, o:Object;

// for()
time = getTimer();
for (i=0; i=0; i--) { arr[i]; }
trace("for reversed test: "+(getTimer()-time)+"ms");

// for..in
time = getTimer();
for each(o in arr) { o; }
trace("for each test: "+(getTimer()-time)+"ms");
```

Results

```
for test: 124ms
for reversed test: 110ms
for each test: 261ms
```